# What are the specifications for "Morse Taper" sizes?

Tags: lathe

I'm not sure what Morse Taper size my lathe centers use: MT#1, MT#2 or MT#3.  Does anyone have a description of what the sizes are (lengths, diameters, etc) for the different MT sizes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information you seek can be found [here](http://littlemachineshop.com/reference/tapers.php).

I've pasted a screenshot below for completeness.

[image]